# nested loop disk access pattern

Tags: sql-server

Inside a nested loop query plan, does sql server wait for one instance of the loop to complete before starting the next one?

I have some queries which are slow and their pattern is index scan->nestedLoop lookup, and i'm reasonably sure that the cache is cold.

Assuming I've a query plan that shows a nested loop with 10000 lookups, If i consistently have a 5ms disk access time, is there any way to work out how long it will take to read the rows (assume 5k page fetches are needed; some of the rows will be on already fetched pages, producting logical but not physical reads).

Comment: For the first question the answer is yes.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318(v=sql.105).aspx .  For 2nd question it is hard to calculate based on physical read. SQL server have mechanism to reduce wait time for physical read, such as read-ahead. It is better to tune by looking at logical read, duration, cpu ms.

Comment: There's also nested loop prefetching: https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2013/08/sql-server-internals-nested-loops-prefetching.html